# Unexpected toPrecision() behavior in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

This one is really confusing me.

```
var a = 0.0003;
var b = a.toPrecision(3);
```

I was expecting b to be "0.000300", and that's exactly what I got in Firefox, IE and Chrome.  But not in Edge.  Edge gave me "0.000200".

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

jsfiddle here if anyone wants to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dajp/2b47qLg0/

(I'm using Edge 40.15063.0.0 with EdgeHTML 15.15063 if that makes a difference.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best method but it fixes the problem on edge.

This is just a modification to your jsfiddle's javascript:

```
runWeirdness = function() {
a = 0.0003;
b = a.toFixed(3 + decimalPlaces(a));
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Answer is: " + b;
}

function decimalPlaces(num) {
  var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
  if (!match) { return 0; }
  return Math.max(
       0,
       // Number of digits right of decimal point.
       (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
       // Adjust for scientific notation.
       - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
}
```

The basic difference between `toFixed()` and `toPrecision()` is that `toFixed(n)` provides an nth length after the decimal point while `toPrecision(x)` provides x total length, including before the decimal point.

Comment: Many thanks... I have since found another method as well, which is accurate enough for my purposes and a bit simpler: if I use 'toPrecision(a + a*1e-6)' instead of 'toPrecision(a)' then Edge gives the answer I expected.  Since in my application I never have 'a' set to something like 0.02999997 I think I can get away with this, though it's a horrible bodge and and I still don't understand why it's happening in the first place.  I like your method much better.

Comment: Yeah, the life of a web developer would be much simpler if all browsers were the same but far less interesting.